# Get the message sid of a response from twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am receiving a message into my api and then processing it. This incoming message api call gives me the "messageSid" of the incoming message. When I process this, the preferred solution seems to be to respond with something like

```
<Response>
 <Message>Thank you</Message>
</Response>
```

This works well, but unfortunately I don't have a Sid for the response message. As both incur charges, is there anyway to get this Sid so I can store it? I'm using C#, but at the moment I'm not using the SDK.

My only thought is to return an empty response and send the reply myself as a new message... but this seems pretty awkward.

I guess I could get it from a callback? (but what if the twilio platform fails and I don't get the callback).

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can't get the SID directly from responding using TwiML.

If you need the SID as soon as you send the message then I recommend your first suggestion, reply with an empty `<Response/>` and [use the REST API to send the SMS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/messaging/send-messages).

Alternatively, you can set the [`action` attribute on the `<Message>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/message#attributes-action) element. The `action` should be a URL and Twilio will make a webhook request to it every time the message changes status. Along with the status, you will also receive the message Sid and all [the standard TwiML message parameters](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request#request-parameters).

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: In the end, I took the first option. I didn't reply directly but generated a new message completely that looked to the receiver as if it was a reply.